# Selenium can't handle new window with edge IE mode C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

For an automation project I have to use selenium webdriver with edge. Unfortunately the site is under IE kernel. So I start edge in IE mode everything works fine. But when the controller needs to detect a new window with windowHandle, it does not detect anything new even with a wait.
Is it possible to make the switch work in IE mode ?

**PS**: As I use an IE driver I can by changing a few lines start IE. When I run IE the window change is done. When I run Edge with the options I don't detect anything. So everything works fine with the IE browser, the problem only comes from edge and the IE mod.

I am using an IE driver with capabilities like this :

```
   var ieService = InternetExplorerDriverService.CreateDefaultService(dir, driver); 
    var ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions{}; 
    ieOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("ie.edgechromium", true); 
    ieOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("ie.edgepath", "{path to msedge.exe}"); 

    var webdriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieService, ieOptions, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("button")).Click(); 
 
Thread.Sleep(2000); 

string popupHandle = string.Empty; 
ReadOnlyCollection<string> windowHandles = driver.WindowHandles;  

foreach (string handle in windowHandles)  
{  
    if (handle != existingWindowHandle)  
    {  
         popupHandle = handle;
         break;  
    }  
}  
driver.SwitchTo().Window(popupHandle);
```

Comment: Can you please post the code you are using, and describe where it is not working as you expect?

Comment: Please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce the issue**. With only the text description, we can't test and find the issue. Besides, can you make it work using selenium IE driver automation? And please clarify more clearly about how does it work fine in IE and not work in Edge.

Comment: @louischaill: Did you find any solution to your problem?

Comment: @harsha.cs no i don't understand why with others that works and not with IE mod

Comment: @louischaill: Had raised Issues in Microsoft in Github and following already raised issue in Selenium Github. Will update you once I get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Now it is solved. You can download latest Selenium version 4.0 and start scripting for Edge in IE Mode. You can also follow the issue ticket in github in the following link [MS Edge in IE Mode](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/8868)